# How did Fire Lord Sozin want to recognize the Avatar?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender

Or how did Sozin know the Avatar wasn't among the airbenders that were killed-off during the genocide? In his will, Sozin made clear that the Avatar, who's the last airbender, escaped from him, respectively the Fire Nation army. How did Sozin know that and how did he want to make out the Avatar among the airbenders?

The Avatar's identity is revealed at age 16, in Aang's case at age 12 but the Fire Lord didn't know that. Did Sozin prepare a trap to let him enter the Avatar state, thus recognizing him, for instance?

Comment: Speculation: He inferred it based on the fact that no new Waterbender Avatar had come forth.

Comment: @gowenfawr The Avatar's identity is revealed at age 16 so that would be 4 years before Sozin's death. Since Sozin writes "I searched for the Avatar the rest of my life" I think he meant the entire time since the Fire Nation killed off the airbenders.